# iOS & Android: Using Apple Music API for commercial use?

Tags: android, ios, apple-music

I'm looking to use [Apple Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi) to search for songs and display them in a list (along with their artists). I'm unclear to whether it is legal to actually do so, with a commercial app.

The reason I ask is because Spotify does not allow the use of their API for commercial application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about legal uses, not about programming.